# Gravity Forms special characters on button

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress with Gravity Forms and I have problems with showing the Submit button with special characters such as ÅÄÖ.

I have UTF-8 set as charset, I have checked with my hosting company and they say that the UTF-8 is set and I have been in contact with GF Support with no luck. This is how it looks:

[image: Button with odd characters]

I have tried in the normal TwentyTwenty theme and there it works, so it has to be something in the theme. Since I'm the creator of the theme I can't contact someone else and really don't know what in the theme I should change. Does anyone know?

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is without looking at the code. Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now.

The problem was in the GF function which transformed the submit button to a button. I added:

```html
$dom->loadHTML( '<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $button );
```

And it worked!